# How to tune a 2 stringed instrument

Tags: theory

I just got a two string instrument. I’m trying to find out how to tune this,I’m assuming it’s High E and B not sure?  Or should they be the same gauge again not sure?

Any experts?

Comment: What is the instrument?

Comment: Just a note, since you're new to the site, although your question has been closed, it can be reopened. Primarily it just needs the critical detail of what the instrument is.

Comment: @Aaron perhaps less critical than the identity of the instrument is what use the owner wants to make of it.  The answer could be different depending on the type of music it's used to play which might not be the music it's designed for.